# How to convert date 22 November 2021 to 22 Nov 2021

Tags: php

Hello i want to convert date to another format. below is what i tried and did not work:

```
    $expirationdate = 22nd November 2021;
    $newDate = date("'d\<\s\u\p\>S\<\/\s\u\p\> F Y", strtotime($expirationdate));
```

Thanks

Comment: You need quotes around the value of `$expirationdate`

Comment: You need to change the `F` in your date format string to `M` https://3v4l.org/5G40a

Answer (score 0):

changr dateformat F to M

```
$expirationdate = '22nd November 2021';
echo $newDate = date('d M Y', strtotime($expirationdate));
```

if you need '22nd'

```
echo $newDate = date('dS M Y', strtotime($expirationdate));
```

Comment: it did not work. it abbreviates the month but gives wrong date. please take note of the format which is not standard: 22nd November 2021